# webpack thinks there is a missing loader

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm taking an Angular 4 app using webpack 2.7 and porting to Angular 9 webpack 4.41.6.

as part of my new webpack.config.js file I have the following loader rules:

```
 rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'ts-loader', query: { silent: true } },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'to-string-loader!css-loader' },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader', query: { limit: 25000 } }
    ]
```

I have installed the 5 loader packages and have them referenced in my package.json file.

When I run `ng build` I receive the following error:

> ERROR in ./src/app/message/message.component.html 1:0 
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) 
>   You may need an appropriate loader to
>   handle this file type, currently no loader s are configured to process
>   this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```
<div> |   <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="goBack()"><i class="f a fa-fw fa-arrow-left"></i>Go
> Back</button> | </div>
```

> @ ./src/app/message/message.component.ts
>   46:18-53
>   @ ./src/app/app.routing.ts
>   @ ./src/app/app.module.ts  @
>   ./src/main.ts
>   @ multi ./src/main.ts

Furthermore both are in visual studio. So in the csproj file of the V4 solution we have:

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="npm install --no-optional" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <_GeneratedFiles Include="$(GeneratedItemPatterns)" />
      <ContentWithTargetPath Include="@(_GeneratedFiles->'%(FullPath)')" RelativePath="%(_GeneratedFiles.Identity)" TargetPath="%(_GeneratedFiles.Identity)" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

but because we are using a later release in the v9 solution's csproj file we have:

```
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

according to the Webpack documentation, as long as the custom webpack.config.js file resides in the root, then it should be picked up automatically. I'm not convinced this is happening, which would account for the error.

Comment: I would run a double check and make sure that those loaders aren't deprecated. Maybe put up your package.json file so we can see which versions you have. Just as an example, I once set up a Vue webpack loader that used `npm i babel/core` instead of `npm i @babel/core`, this caused massive problems for me despite not showing any errors when downloading.

Comment: @emoore I've installed the latest versions of the loaders. I think the issue is that the custom webpack.config.js file isn't being picked up. I've added more to my question

Comment: You could try forcing it to happen with a build event. You can right click on your csproj and click properties. Then select build events, and in the Pre-build section add something along the lines of  `cd {to_your_webpack_directory}` and follow it up with `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js`. It's not a permanent solution, but it should confirm if VS is not picking up your config file.